# Maven release plugin fail to push tags in the prepare goal

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, bitbucket, maven-release-plugin

Using Bitbucket 6.0.1, Maven 3.6.2, release plugin 2.5.3, git 2.13.2
Jenkins execute a job for creating the release, when doing the checkout operation I can see a correct url for the git repo.

```
2019-Nov-13_1810 Building remotely on Slave09 in workspace C:/workspace/Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build
2019-Nov-13_1810  > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1810 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
2019-Nov-13_1810  > git.exe config remote.origin.url ssh://git@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1810 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git
2019-Nov-13_1810  > git.exe --version # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1810  > git.exe fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1811 Checking out Revision 98c3ca202fc6f8388600858d7b9c43ef960962e4 (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe checkout -f 98c3ca202fc6f8388600858d7b9c43ef960962e4
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe branch -D develop # timeout=10
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe checkout -b develop 98c3ca202fc6f8388600858d7b9c43ef960962e4
2019-Nov-13_1811 Commit message: "pom.xml edited online with Bitbucket"
2019-Nov-13_1811  > git.exe rev-list --no-walk 98c3ca202fc6f8388600858d7b9c43ef960962e4 # timeout=10
```

the correct url is :

```
ssh://git@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git
```

but when the tagging phase runs, something is messing with the url:

```
2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git symbolic-ref HEAD"

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Working directory: C:\workspace\Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build\tashtit.parent

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh:********@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git refs/heads/develop:refs/heads/develop"

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Working directory: C:\workspace\Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build\tashtit.parent

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Tagging release with the label tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911131852...

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git tag -F C:\Users\TVLRTC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-1423733870.commit tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911131852"

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Working directory: C:\workspace\Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push ssh:********@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas refs/tags/tashtit.spring_build_1902.01.1911131852"

2019-Nov-13_1855 [INFO] Working directory: C:\workspace\Tashtit-Spring-Dev-Build
```

as you can see the url is broken:

```
git push ssh:********@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas
```

it should display the above url
the Jenkins job run this command from a script:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare -Dtag=${teamName}_build_$releaseVersion -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DreleaseVersion=$releaseVersion -DdevelopmentVersion=0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Here is the error:

```
2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project tashtit.parent: Unable to tag SCM

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] Provider message:

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] The git-push command failed.

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] Command output:

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] Repository not found

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] 

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR] and the repository exists.

2019-Nov-13_1855 [ERROR]
```

Here is the SCM part from the pom:

```
<scm>
        <url>http://pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7990/scm/tas/tashtit.git</url>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@pa2vmp56.blmain.prod:7999/tas/tashtit.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
```

only this repo is doing troubles, we have more git repos under other projects that are working just fine.
any ideas?

Comment: Check your pom file for scm entry which contains the URL ...furthermore I don't see any error message..

Comment: You are right, one of the developers that try to figure it out left some wrong code. I fixed it but still the original problem is still exist, the tag using a broken url. I edit the question with the correct info.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I added the SCM connection to the question, as you can see, it is correct, am I missing something?

Comment: Can you access the repository by hand..Have you checked the command line: `git remote -v` is the same as in the pom file? Cause the errors show permission/`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`... ?

Comment: yes, I can access the repository, the remote is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happens, I think it is related to the flat structure of the git repo.
In the Jenkins Job I sent two parameters (that was fit to the previous structure) like that:

```
parent.folder=tashtit.parent
ear.folder=../tashtit.spring.junits/target
```

After changing the structure to include the parent pom as a flat-file and not in a maven project of its own, I changed the parameters like that:

```
parent.folder=.
ear.folder=tashtit.spring.junits/target
```

From that point, everything starts working as it should.